# 4TB drive corrupted partition now appearing as 129986TB

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, ntfs

The drive (Seagate IronWolf ST4000VN008 - 4 TB) got 2 partitions before and both partitions cannot be opened.

I managed to recover the second partition by running `chkdsk F: /f /x /r` Although its weird since the partition is now reported as FAT32 when I believe it is NTFS before but I can open the files on that partition without issues.

I tried chkdsk the first partition but I am getting

```
The type of the file system is ntfs.
Unable to determine volume version and state. chkdsk aborted.
```

I am trying testdisk now but one issue is its incorrect size. Will it damage the drive if the drive is reporting a different size. I tried modifying the CHS to correct the size reported by testdisk. I found `16383 16 63` as the values posted on one of the spec sheet of the drive( https://www.bhphotovideo.com/lit_files/361144.pdf ) but it is not correct when entered on testdisk.

I have another 1TB drive and check its CHS and modified it to get 4TB/ The default CHS of the 4TB drive is `2756371791 / 255 / 63` which gives the petabyte size. I change it to `486402 / 255 / 63` to get 4TB
(I know the 4TB drive might have a different value since its a different drive but I just want to see if it can find my partition). Right now it is still scanning.

```
Disk /dev/sdb - 4000 GB / 3726 GiB - CHS 486402 255 63
Analyse cylinder 486401/486401: 99%
                                    
MS Data                    32768 4096032767 4096000000
MS Data               4096032768 7814033407 3718000640
```

Any other software I can use to recover my partition?

Comment: Computers haven't used CHS addressing for the last 20-30 years, so the CHS numbers shown by testdisk are just made-up. Not entirely sure why it even shows them.

Comment: Nice I did not know that. But after changing it on testdisk the correct size is now appearing on windows disk management.